# Sometime I see my 'vi' takes really long time(~2min) in 'bash', but it is pretty quick in 'tcsh'. How do I resolve this?

Tags: linux

```
uname -a
Linux eng-user3 3.11.0-20-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 21:32:55 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am able to run `cat` on same file in both `bash` and `tcsh`.

Comment: Does that happen always when opening a certain file?

Comment: No, it happens with every file I try.

Comment: What happens if you try to open it with `vim -u NONE`? If this fixes your problem, then one of the scripts is slowing down vim. You can see what scripts you have loaded with `:scriptnames`.